# Dragging an input field value over multiple pages

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm not sure what approach to follow here... I need users to enter new products. Because of screen space limits, I decided it should be a three step wizard. First page they enter product brand, next page the collection name and third page the actual name. I'm using a form on each page for this.

What is the best way to bring the values of the previous input field to the next page? Should I do an OnLoad javascript action and put the $POST value from previous page in a hidden form field? Should I store them in session cookies? What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: This is what sessions are for

Comment: Or use hidden input field on next form to store previous form value :)

Comment: :-) Ok, I'll go with the sessions. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of solutions:

1) Using Post vars and hidden input tags on the other pages, this will work.

2) Using Sessions vars... this is similar to the Post solution and can work. (Better than solution 1).

3) You can do this three steps wizard with "tabs" without changing page... with this you can as example have a Javascript vars to store "for some time" the data. It can works.

All depends on what you want.